# What tools should I use to create a tutorial for my web application?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I'm imagining an overlay that covers most of the site, focusing in on sections with explanatory text and the ability to move forward or backward. Ideally, some of the functionality of the site will still be available so if a user clicks on a button in the highlighted area it will work as intended, just in the background.

I know I could use jQuery to do this but I'm curious if there is a framework or library that does what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Dmitriy Naumov's answer and the lack of other responses I ended up going with a jQuery-based solution.

In order to achieve the overlay effect that I wanted I used jQuery Tools' [Expose](http://flowplayer.org/tools/toolbox/expose.html) tool.

I placed the overlay and then faded the elements I wanted to highlight in and out, manipulating their z-indices to move them in front of or behind the overlay as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to cover web applications' functionality and not to loose sufficient level of interactivity.  But instead of data exchange with database - you can populate your controls with data from JavaScript array. And to simulate event results (form submit, etc.). Simple JavaScript can help you with that.
I don't think that there are existing JavaScript libraries that can simulate more complicated functionality specific for your site.

Comment: True enough. I'm wondering if the 'overlay' with highlighting that I'm imagining is available anywhere. Thanks for the answer.